# Is there a command to clean the entire front end? How?

Tags: front-end, syntax

I usually work with small pieces of code that result in numbers or text, and I clean up a little at a time to start again.

I have searched here in the forum and in the mathematica help for something to clear the screen something like a "clear screen or cls".

The idea is to leave clean the screen for future executions of some program (English is not one of the best).

Comment: Are you working in notebooks? If you want to remove all output then do `Cell->Delete all output`. If you want to delete all input and output cells, you can right click to select all cells and select `cut`. Mathematica is not like Matlab. There is no `console`. Everything is done inside the notebook.

Comment: To clear variables and function definitions you defined in context Global, you may say: `Clear["Global`*"]`